# "Transpose-esque" - T/SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (NAME varchar(10), DOB Datetime2, Location varchar(50), Phone int)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (NAME, DOB, Location, Phone)
SELECT 'Name1','2000-01-01','USA',1234567890
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2','2000-01-02','CAN',0987654321

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

/*
Current Output

```
NAME    DOB                         Location    Phone
Name1   2000-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 USA         1234567890
Name2   2000-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 CAN         987654321
```

Desired Output

```
Catagory    N1              N2          ...Nn
            'NAME1'         'Name2'
DOB         '2000-01-01'    '2000-01-02'
Location    'USA'           'CAN'
Phone       1234567890      0987654321
```

Catagory, N1, N2,...Nn are column names (Nn = there can be dynamica number of "Name"
There is no catagory name for 'Name1,'Name2',...'Namen'
Not sure how to do this properly...XML maybe? Please help!
*/

Thank you

Comment: I am not to familiar with pivot but don't I need use some sort of aggregation for pivot? Not sure what aggregation I would use for this scenario.---Maybe unpivot? trying now.

Comment: select *
from
(
  select Name, DOB, Location, Phone
  from @TABLE
) x
pivot
(
  max(Phone)
  for Name in([Name1], [Name2])
)p  -- hhahahaha! Not even close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result but you will need to use a few other functions first to get the final product.

First, you will want to create a unique sequence for each row (it doesn't look like you have one), this value is going to be used to create your final list of new columns.  You can use `row_number()` to create this value:

```
select name, dob, location, phone,
  row_number() over(order by name) seq
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8b33/2). Once you have created this unique value then you can unpivot the multiple columns of data `name`, `dob`, `location` and `phone`.  Depending on your version of SQL Server you can use the unpivot function or CROSS APPLY:

```
select 'N'+cast(seq as varchar(10)) seq,
  category, value, so
from
(
  select name, dob, location, phone,
    row_number() over(order by name) seq
  from yourtable
) src
cross apply
(
  select 'name', name, 1 union all
  select 'DOB', convert(varchar(10), dob, 120), 2 union all
  select 'Location', location, 3 union all
  select 'Phone', cast(phone as varchar(15)), 4
) c (category, value, so);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8b33/3).  This will get your data in the format:

```
| SEQ | CATEGORY |      VALUE | SO |
|-----|----------|------------|----|
|  N1 |     name |      Name1 |  1 |
|  N1 |      DOB | 2000-01-01 |  2 |
|  N1 | Location |        USA |  3 |
|  N1 |    Phone | 1234567890 |  4 |
```

Now you can easily apply the PIVOT function:

```
SELECT category, n1, n2 
FROM 
(
  select 'N'+cast(seq as varchar(10)) seq,
    category, value, so
  from
  (
    select name, dob, location, phone,
      row_number() over(order by name) seq
    from yourtable
  ) src
  cross apply
  (
    select 'name', name, 1 union all
    select 'DOB', convert(varchar(10), dob, 120), 2 union all
    select 'Location', location, 3 union all
    select 'Phone', cast(phone as varchar(15)), 4
  ) c (category, value, so)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for seq in (N1, N2)
) piv
order by so;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8b33/4). The above works great if you have a limited number of values but if you will have an unknown number of `names`, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('N'+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(order by name) seq
                      from yourtable
                    )d
                    group by seq
                    order by seq
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT category, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select ''N''+cast(seq as varchar(10)) seq,
                category, value, so
              from
              (
                select name, dob, location, phone,
                  row_number() over(order by name) seq
                from yourtable
              ) src
              cross apply
              (
                select ''name'', name, 1 union all
                select ''DOB'', convert(varchar(10), dob, 120), 2 union all
                select ''Location'', location, 3 union all
                select ''Phone'', cast(phone as varchar(15)), 4
              ) c (category, value, so)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by so'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8b33/6). They both give a result of:

```
| CATEGORY |         N1 |         N2 |
|----------|------------|------------|
|     name |      Name1 |      Name2 |
|      DOB | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-02 |
| Location |        USA |        CAN |
|    Phone | 1234567890 |  987654321 |
```

Comment: Holy cow! This will take a bit to ingest but get's the desired output. wow!...just wow!!! Thank you so much for your time.